# LogStash concat Filebeat input

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am trying to merge filebeat messages in LogStash.
I have the next Log file:

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 8520944
Engine version: 0.102.4
Scanned directories: 408
Scanned files: 1688
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 50
Data scanned: 8.93 MB
Data read: 4.42 MB (ratio 2.02:1)
Time: 22.052 sec (0 m 22 s)
```

I read it from Filebeat and send to LogStash.

The problem is that I received in LogStash each line in different message. I want to merge it all, and also add a new field that is "received_at", from the fileBeat input.

I would like to have the next output from LogStash:

```
{
  Known_viruses: 8520944
  Engine_version: 0.102.4
  Scanned_directories: 408
  Scanned_files: 1688
  Infected_files: 0
  Total_errors: 50
  Data_scanned: 8.93MB
  Data_read: 4.42MB
  Time: 22.052sec (0 m 22 s)
  Received_at: <timeStamp taked from filebeat received JSON message>
}
```

The input I received in LogStash from Filebeat is the next per each line:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-04-20T08:03:33.843Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "tags": ["beats_input_codec_plain_applied"],
    "host": {
        "name": "PRLN302",
        "architecture": "x86_64",
        "ip": ["10.126.40.18", "fe80::7dbf:4941:cd39:c0f9", "172.17.0.1", "fe80::42:82ff:fe2b:895", "fe80::24b2:8cff:feeb:20b4", "172.18.0.1", "fe80::42:53ff:fe31:a025", "fe80::b420:e1ff:fe97:c152", "fe80::9862:21ff:fe3a:c33e", "fe80::48a6:70ff:fec2:60d6", "192.168.126.117", "fe80::2831:c644:33d5:321"],
        "id": "a74e193a551f4d379f9488b80a463581",
        "os": {
            "platform": "ubuntu",
            "version": "20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)",
            "family": "debian",
            "name": "Ubuntu",
            "type": "linux",
            "codename": "focal",
            "kernel": "5.8.0-49-generic"
        },
        "mac": ["e8:6a:64:32:fe:4d", "dc:8b:28:4a:c8:88", "02:42:82:2b:08:95", "26:b2:8c:eb:20:b4", "02:42:53:31:a0:25", "b6:20:e1:97:c1:52", "9a:62:21:3a:c3:3e", "4a:a6:70:c2:60:d6", "00:50:b6:b9:19:d7"],
        "containerized": false,
        "hostname": "PRLN302"
    },
    "message": "----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------",
    "agent": {
        "ephemeral_id": "ad402f64-ab73-480c-b6de-4af6184f012c",
        "type": "filebeat",
        "version": "7.12.0",
        "id": "f681d775-d452-490a-9b8b-036466a87d35",
        "name": "PRLN302",
        "hostname": "PRLN302"
    },
    "input": {
        "type": "log"
    },
    "ecs": {
        "version": "1.8.0"
    },
    "log": {
        "offset": 0,
        "file": {
            "path": "/var/log/clamav-test.log"
        }
    }
}
```

Could it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you'll need to look for the multiline messages in the filebeat input:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html
somthing like below would do it i think:

```
multiline.type: pattern
multiline.pattern: '^----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------'
multiline.negate: true
multiline.match: after
```

Comment: just added the config that should work for your given input

Comment: This was my log. But I read the Log from filebeat and send to LogStash. So in LogStash I think I receive a JSON. You can check at the end of my question. (Updated)

Comment: Is it possible to add the config of the filebeat input? (mask the output parts where needed), indeed Logstash is receiving json normally seen

Comment: I need to make it in LogStash. I think the problem is in LogStash, doesn't made anything. Always the output is the same as the input.

Comment: No the problem lies in the fact that filebeat send it as separate events, Logstash cannot concat these, you need to do this in filebeat prior to going to logstash as logstash can get multiple events at the same time and cannot know if it was part of A B or C, and filebeat knows it upon reading...

Comment: Thanks! I accept your answer because it works with Filebeat.